# RowHeight property of ListView not working on UWP project

Tags: listview, xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` with a row height set. This is working on iOS and Android, but not on UWP. Here the height of the row is very small. It is as big as the default font size of `TextCell`. I made another small sample project with this code:

```
Title = "Page";
var listView = new ListView
{
    RowHeight = 44,
};
listView.ItemsSource = new string[]
{
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
    "Test5",
};

Content = listView;
```

This code is working fine on the sample project, but not in the big main project.

Has anybody a clue why `RowHeight` isn't working here?

Comment: I had had issues while combining RowHeight with Vertical and Horizontal Options of the Cell and its containers so watch out! for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in Xamarin.Forms 2.1.0. Hope this will get be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the xLabs repeater and surely it should work for your listview as well?

I use the ChildAdded Event Property on the ViewCell and format it on the codebehind.... Hey... It works!

```
                  <!--Users added go here-->              
      <xLabs:RepeaterView x:TypeArguments="models:User" x:Name="UsersAddedStack" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding UsersAdded}" ItemClickCommand="{Binding AddedUserIconClicked}" Spacing="4">

        <xLabs:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>                    
            <ViewCell ChildAdded="RepeaterChild_OnChildAdded"><!-- <====fixes height -->
              <Frame Padding="0,6,0,6" OutlineColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="user256blue.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                  <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <!--First Name + Last Name-->
                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                         BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"/>
                    <!--Username-->
                    <Label Text="{Binding Username}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                         BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
              </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>                  
        </xLabs:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>


      </xLabs:RepeaterView>
```

---

```
private void RepeaterChild_OnChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
{
    var viewCell = sender as ViewCell;
    viewCell.View.HeightRequest = _ccfvm.IconHeight; //_ccfvm is my viewmodel for the page
}
```